# Can't uninstall redmine plugin

Tags: uninstallation, redmine-plugins

I followed instructions and do this:

1. `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production` //success
2. remove plugin from the plugins folder
3. bundle install { do this after some attempt uninstall plugin }
4. reboot redmine

and afterwards (when I starting redmine) I get an error:

```
Exiting ../lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': 
No such file to load -- #{RAILS_ROOT}/plugins/plugins/{name_of_plugin}/init (LoadError)
```

Also I tried to do:

`bundle exec rake -T` and disabled tasks associated with plugin,

but it is all don't work.
Help, please t__t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to another plugin related to this.
Solved by removing related plugins.